# ANR on the emulator keyboard application

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-anr-dialog

I have an application and I'm trying to test it on the emulator, and most of the times I get an ANR. However, it's not on my application, but on the keyboard application. Is there something wrong I might be doing that causes this, or is it an issue of the emulator that doesn't affect actual devices and I can ignore it? Thanks.

Comment: are you seeing this through monkey or manually interacting with the emulator?

Comment: It's not through Monkey. I get it when I press the "menu" button on the emulator to enter to the application after it's installed.